# Recommended way to make an object's member variable accessible to other classes?

Tags: c++, object

```
//Foo.h

class Foo
{
public:
    SomeApiType ApiObj;
};

//Foo.cpp

Foo::Foo()
{
    ApiObj = SomeApiFunction();
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    ApiFreeObj(ApiObj);
}

//main.cpp

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    // various code
    return 0;
}
```

So what is the recommended way to make `foo.ApiObj` accessible to other classes?

```
//Bar.cpp
Bar::Bar()
{
    BarMember = OtherApiFunction(foo.ApiOjb); // make it accessible here
}
```

It works if `Foo foo` is global but I don't prefer this way.

If it is global, does it's destructor is called in `return 0` ?

Comment: Another class to use it or access it. Are you just looking for a `get()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Um, pass a *reference to `Foo`*?

```
Bar::Bar([const] Foo& foo) {
      // ^^^^^^^   really depends on your case
    BarMember = OtherApiFunction(foo.ApiOjb); // make it accessible here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of inheritance. In this was you inherit few features from base class to derived class

```
class Bar : private Foo
{
    // BarMembers
}

//Bar.cpp
Bar::Bar()
{
    BarMember = OtherApiFunction(foo.ApiOjb); // make it accessible here
}
```

I used **private (access-specifier)** so as to make the **public members** from class **Foo**, **private** in class **Bar**.

You can use other access-specifier too.

For more on inheritance:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm